# React: ERROR does not match the corresponding name on disk

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
ERROR: Failed to compile.

./src/places/components/PlaceList.js
Cannot find file: 'Card.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\src\Shared\components\UIElements\shared'.
```

I am getting this error even though I have checked my path, I cant understand why I am getting this error. Look into the image:

[image]

Comment: You're using an upper case `S` letter in `Shared` when trying to import the component, whilst the folder name is `shared` with a lower case `s`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to replace **'Card.css'** to **'card.css'** in that ***Card.js*** component. You should be import ***'Card.js'*** Module properly in ***PlaceList.js*** component.